# Matrix form of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,V_2))$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be respectively a $n$-dimensional and $m$-dimensional vector space. Consider the vector space $\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,V_2)$ of linear homomorphism from $V_1$ to $V_2$. This vector space is isomorphic to the vector space of $(m \times n)$-matrices and is therefore $mn$-dimensional. Let $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,V_2))$ be the vector space of automorphisms of $\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,V_2)$. Just as in we should consider $\mathrm{GL}(V_1)$ this vector space should have a matrix representations and thus those elements need to have a trace en determinant. I understand those abstract concepts but it isn't clear to me how you would calculate such a trace or determinant. Moreover, how do you write an element of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,V_2))$ in matrix form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is easier to handle $GL(\hom(V_1,V_2))$ as the group of *invertible* linear transformations $\varphi:\hom(V_1,V_2)\to\hom(V_1,V_2)\ $ (i.e. for which this mapping has an inverse $\varphi^{-1}$).

However, if one insists, can write up matrix forms as well, as follows:

$\hom(V_1,V_2)$ has a basis of matrices $e_{ij}$ in which there is a $1$ at $i,j$ and $0$ everywhere else $(i=1...n,\ j=1...m)$. So, a $\varphi\in GL(\hom(V_1,V_2))$ will have a matrix whose column of index $(i,j)$ (out of the $nm$ columns) will be the ($nm$ dimensional) vector $\ \varphi(e_{ij})\,$.

In particular, ${\rm tr}(\varphi)=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}{e_{ij}}^T\varphi(e_{ij})\ =\ \sum_{i,j}((i,j)$th coordinate of $\varphi(e_{ij}))$.